Authorizing Flutter app to access cloudflare protected website
Is there an api or way to be able to bypass cloudflare human verification in my flutter app?
My flutter app is getting data from a website, is there a settings where this request from an app can be authorized? Or an api token that does not need to have a human verification.
My app is getting an error 403
cloudflare turnstile dart package

if the api is secured by a cloudflare turnstile ,then you need to pass the header "CCApp" true value then response is 200 ok

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If the API is secured by a Turnstile, then you need a Turnstile Widget SiteKey to generate a token in your Flutter application (you can use the cloudflare_turnstile package) to attach to your API request. I don't think it can be avoided.
